# Merge tags [queryover] and [nhibernate-queryover]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I suggest that the tags [queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryover) and [nhibernate-queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover) should be merged into [nhibernate-queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover), as they mean the same thing.

From Tag-Wiki:

- [queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryover) QueryOver is a strongly-typed fluent-like wrapper on top of NHibernate ICritieria, a database-agnostic query API that supports query composition.
- [nhibernate-queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover) NHibernate QueryOver is a strongly-typed fluent-like wrapper on top of NHibernate ICritieria, a database-agnostic query API that supports query composition.